# Javascript radio button like checkbox check/unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a radio button behave like a check box being able to check/unchecked. the problem is because the script is activated by the click event which colors the label.

HTML code

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>16:00-17.30</td>
        <td><label for="date_last07">19.Deployment event - matchmaking session</label></td>
        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input style="display:none;" id="date_last07" name="date_last01" type="radio" value="07" />
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='date_last01']").click(function() {    
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("label[for='date_last"+test+"']").css("background-color", "yellow");
        $("input[name='date_last01']").prop('checked', false);
        $("input[name='date_last01']").prop('checked', true);
    }); 
});
```

CSS code

```
tr {
    height: 1px;
}
td{
    height: 100%;
}
label{
    display: block; 
    min-height: 100%; /* for the latest browsers which support min-height */
    height: auto !important; /* for newer IE versions */
    height: 100%; /* the only height-related attribute that IE6 does not ignore  */
}
label:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upR8t/

Comment: what do you want to do if it is unchecked ? change back to original color of label ? And why radio button only ?

Comment: mate, change it to a checkbox...what'll be the difference? it's hidden anyway ;)

Comment: so when will it be unchecked ? in you example it will always be unchecked , when do you wan it to be unchecked ?

Comment: There are more radio buttons (not included) but this one has no brother by name and i need to offer a user a way to uncheck it and return to normal with no bg and not being checked

Comment: try making a checkbox act like a radio, that would be much easier. p.s. it's much better to use div or span in your case.